# How to get textbox value without using form action and assign it to a PHP variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I just want to ask a simple question. I am creating a validation form using PHP. And what I need to do is to get the value of my textbox and assign it to a variable. Because I need that variable for comparing. But this process is done without an action form like GET or POST. How can I create a simple jquery for this?

Here's my sample flow.

```
<?php

    $data_qty = fn_product_qty($product_id);
    $x = //should be the textbox qty

    if($x != $data_qty){
       //some code here....
    }
?>
.....
<input type='text' name='qty' value='1' />
```

Comment: use ajax to send the data and get on PHP

Comment: php is executed on the server, you can't pass a javascript variable to php without reloading the page

Comment: so it is not possible? I am thingking of using a session but I don't have an idea.

Comment: Either use AJAX to perform a server-side validation or try and move the validation to the client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax to do this. Can do alot of things, using [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).
Usually when i used to compare username exists in my server-side db i extend a method from jquery validation. Glad to post it here if u'd like

```
   $.ajax({
                        url: "/Mycheckingaction",
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { id: $('input[name="qty"]').val(); },
                        success: function (response, textStatus, xhr) {
                                 if(!response)
                                 {
                                     alert('Error,not equal');     
                                 }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in `javascript` like,

```
<script>
    var x='<?php echo $x;?>';
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        var qty=$('input[name="qty"]').val();
        if(x!=qty){
           alert('Both are not equal');
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you want in server side then use `jquery ajax` and `php $_SESSION` to compare both values.